# plotting barchart in popup using leaflet library

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio, googlevis

Quick question all.
I have some data in sql server which i have loaded into RStudio. I have made a barchart for the data and now i am using leaflet library with the use of latitude and longitude to plot a point on the map. I want to be able to use popup to show a barchart in it when the user clicks on the point.

BarChart code (maybe this is a problem because i am using googleVis library so not sure if i can use this in the popup. but again this is the most appropriate bar graph i can make and need- other suggestions could be helpful as i am not a professional in R libraries yet)

```
Switzerland <- sqlQuery(con, "sql query")
SwitzerlandChart <- gvisBarChart(Switzerland, options = list(height=200))
```

For the graph plot the code is:

```
m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addCircles(lng=8.498868, lat=46.9221, popup=paste(plot(SwitzerlandChart)))
```

When i run this code it opens a webpage to view my barplot.
Then i run the following:

```
m #Prints the graph
```

This prints the graph with the point in the desired location but the popup shows me a webpage instead which also only i can open.

I want to be able to plot the bargraph inside the popup please.

Hope someone can help

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: my select statement is: SELECT distinct region + ', ' + city as Location, count(country) as [CountVis]
                      FROM DATABASE WHERE Country = 'Switzerland' 
                      GROUP BY country, region, city.                                                                                                               Data is: Location- Geneva, Zurich; CountVis- 1, 15 (this is what i plot the barchart with.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe a little late but here's a solution. The `addPopups()` function in `library(leaflet)` seems to be able to handle `.svg` files. Therefore, you could simply save your plot using `svg()` and then read it again using `readLines()`. Here's a reproducible example using `library(mapview)`:

```
library(lattice)
library(mapview)
library(sp)

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")

clr <- rep("grey", length(meuse))

fldr <- tempfile()
dir.create(fldr)

pop <- lapply(seq(length(meuse)), function(i) {

  clr[i] <- "red"
  p <- xyplot(meuse$cadmium ~ meuse$copper, 
              col = clr, pch = 20, alpha = 0.7)

  svg(filename = paste(fldr, "test.svg", sep = "/"), 
      width = 250 * 0.01334, height = 250 * 0.01334)
  print(p)
  dev.off()

  tst <- paste(readLines(paste(fldr, "test.svg", sep = "/")), collapse = "")

  return(tst)

})

mapview(meuse, popup = pop, cex = "cadmium")
```

You will see that each popup is a scatterplot. As for a `leaflet` example, consider this:

```
content <- pop[[1]]
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addPopups(-122.327298, 47.597131, content,
            options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE)
  )
```

In case you need the plot to be interactive, you could have a look at `library(gridSVG)` which is able to produce interactive svg plots from e.g. `lattice` or `ggplot2` plots.

**UPDATE:**

`library(mapview)` now has designated functionality for this:

- `popupGraph`: to embed **lattice**, **ggplot2** or interactive **hatmlwidgets** based plots.
- `popupImage`: to embed local or remote (web) images

This is currently only available in the development version of **mapview** which can be installed with:

```
devtools::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/mapview", ref = "develop"
```

Comment: is it possible to combine popupGraph and popupTable? For example: mapview(meuse, popup = popupGraph(p, type = "svg", width = 3, height = 2.5), popup = popupTable(meuse, z="cadmium")) does not work. I would like to add an image above the table.

Comment: Nope, this is not possible with any of the currently available functions in **mapview**. I think it could be possible though. Basically, one would need to combine the two html strings from the `popup*` functions.

Comment: @MLavoie Turns out you can just paste them together 

`library(mapview)
library(lattice)

poptab = popupTable(breweries[1, ])
popgrph = popupGraph(graphs = lattice::xyplot(1:10 ~ 10:1))
tst = paste(popgrph[[1]], poptab[[1]])
mapview(breweries[1, ], popup = tst)
`

Comment: I tried to use mapview::popupGraph and I get a result saying it is now deprecated. And leaflet does not have popupGraph

Comment: The first example provided above causes R to crash. It displays something for a little while in the plot window and looks like it may be working but the CPU gets going with a bit of intensity and after a few seconds R shutsdown

Answer (score 3):

This may be a little late too, but here is a full leaflet implementation.  I first create the plot and then use the popupGraph function to add it in.

```
# make a plot of the two columns in the dataset
p <- xyplot(Home ~ Auto, data = Jun, col = "orange", pch = 20, cex = 2)

# make one for each data point
p <- mget(rep("p", length(Jun)))

# color code it so that the corresponding points are dark green
clr <- rep("orange", length(Jun))
p <- lapply(1:length(p), function(i) {
  clr[i] <- "dark green"
  update(p[[i]], col = clr)
})


# now make the leaflet map
m1 <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(lng = -72, lat = 41, zoom = 8) %>%


  # add the markers for the Jun dataset
  # use the popupGraph function
  addCircleMarkers(data = Jun, lat = ~Lat, lng = ~Lon,
                   color = ~beatCol(BeatHomeLvl), popup = popupGraph(p),
                   radius = ~sqrt(BeatHome*50), group = 'Home - Jun') %>%


  # layer control
  addLayersControl(
    overlayGroups = c('Home - Jun'
    ),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = F)
  ) %>%



  # legend for compare to average

  addLegend('bottomright', pal = beatCol, values = last$BeatTotalLvl,
            title = 'Compare<br>Quote Count to<br>3Mos State Avg',
            opacity = 1)

m1
```

Here is the output.
[image]

Comment: You can also make the plots in ggplot and add them: `p <- ggplot(Jun, aes(x = Auto, y = Home)) + geom_point(col = "orange", pch = 20, cex = 2) + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y~x) + xlim(0,1500)`

Comment: When I run the `lapply` command, I get:    Error in update.default(p[[i]], col = clr) : 
  need an object with call component     Any ideas why?

Comment: @Ben you need to make sure that you have the sp, lattice and map view library installed.

Comment: I tried to use mapview::popupGraph and I get a result saying it is now deprecated. And leaflet does not have popupGraph

Comment: It is a warning, but you need to read it.  The warning indicates to use `'leafpop::popupGraph` so you need to install the `leafpop` package.