# Whilst using `update` thwarted with Error: need an object with call component

Tags: r, leaflet, lapply

I'm using lapply and `update` to create a series of colors to include in a series of `ggplot` pop-ups.  The plots are to appear in a `leaflet` map, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352539/plotting-barchart-in-popup-using-leaflet-library). What is the "need an object with call component" error all about, and how do I resolve it?

```
x<-structure(list(FacilName = c("ALL ABOU", "ANITA BR", "RAINBOW ", "RANEY DA", "CAS DONO", "A HOME A", "COURT TI", "ECONOMY "), 
              lon = c(-79.8466921, -79.9265183, -80.240089, -79.7807676, -79.8687159, -79.8064845, -79.8527703, -80.2034522), 
              lat = c(40.5808574, 40.2919276, 40.6674307, 40.5880096, 40.1815023, 40.3850284, 40.2577138, 40.6867816), 
              HC01_VC04 = c(4370L, 7700L, 1056L, 584L, 2318L, 1029L, 5053L, 4202L), 
              HC01_VC87 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 31L, 0L, 6L, 22L), 
              IDnum = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18")), row.names = 11:18, class = "data.frame")


p<-ggplot(x, aes(HC01_VC87,HC01_VC04))+geom_point() # construct a basic plot
p<-mget(rep("p",length(x$FacilName)))  # create a set of plots to pop-up in map with `mget`

clr <- rep("orange", length(x$FacilName))    # default color in scatterplot

# create points that indicates specific facility when popup opens
# error occurs here
p <- lapply(1:length(p), function(i) {
clr[i] <- "dark green"
update(p[[i]], col = clr)  })

# map this (will throw error because previous command throws error)
library(leaflet);library(mapview)
leaflet() %>% addTiles()%>%
addCircleMarkers(data=x,label=x$FacilName,
               weight = .4,fillOpacity = 1,radius = 4,
               popup = popupGraph(p))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the `sessionInfo()` for mine and it is the following:

[image]

So, it looks like we do have some version differences which may be part of the problem.  I just installed R last week on a new computer.

Also, it does not look like it likes a ggplot object.

Below is my full working code.  I commented out your ggplot and added the library regal.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)
library(lattice)
library(mapview)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

x<-structure(list(FacilName = c("ALL ABOU", "ANITA BR", "RAINBOW ", "RANEY DA", "CAS DONO", "A HOME A", "COURT TI", "ECONOMY "), 
                  lon = c(-79.8466921, -79.9265183, -80.240089, -79.7807676, -79.8687159, -79.8064845, -79.8527703, -80.2034522), 
                  lat = c(40.5808574, 40.2919276, 40.6674307, 40.5880096, 40.1815023, 40.3850284, 40.2577138, 40.6867816), 
                  HC01_VC04 = c(4370L, 7700L, 1056L, 584L, 2318L, 1029L, 5053L, 4202L), 
                  HC01_VC87 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 31L, 0L, 6L, 22L), 
                  IDnum = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18")), row.names = 11:18, class = "data.frame")

# commented out ggplot do not run the plot below
# p<-ggplot(x, aes(HC01_VC87,HC01_VC04))+geom_point() # construct a basic plot

# note using lattice and making xyplot
p <- xyplot(HC01_VC04 ~ HC01_VC87, data = x, col = "orange", pch = 20, cex = 2)

p<-mget(rep("p",length(x)))  # create a set of plots to pop-up in map with `mget`

clr <- rep("orange", length(x))    # default color in scatterplot

# create points that indicates specific facility when popup opens
# error occurs here
p <- lapply(1:length(p), function(i) {
    clr[i] <- "dark green"
    update(p[[i]], col = clr)  })

# map this (will throw error because previous command throws error)
m <- leaflet() %>% 
    addTiles()%>%
    addCircleMarkers(data=x,label=x$FacilName,
                     weight = .4,fillOpacity = 1,radius = 4,
                     popup = popupGraph(p)) 

m
```

I get the output below with colors.

[image]

Comment: The issue seems to be with `ggplot`.  When I run your code with `xyplot` all is good; with `ggplot` I throw the "need an object with call component" error.  Thanks!

Comment: Great - yes, my original was an xyplot.  I think that the list format of ggplot cannot be appended too easily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the following packages are installed:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)
library(lattice)
library(mapview)
library(sp)
```

I ran all of your code after installing the libraries and it works.

Mapview requires the 'sf' package which can be difficult to install depending on your system.

[image]

Comment: Bryan, the `sf` package loads with no issue, but I'm still throwing an error. My R ver 3.5.1 session info shows:       attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] leaflet_2.0.2   forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.0.1   purrr_0.3.2     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_0.8.3    
 [8] tibble_2.1.1    ggplot2_3.1.1   tidyverse_1.2.1 expss_0.8.10    RODBC_1.3-15    sf_0.7-3        lattice_0.20-38
[15] mapview_2.6.3   sp_1.3-1